# Llamar funcion de un formulario hijo que esta dentro de un panel c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tengo esta duda de como llamar una funcion, tengo un formulario que maneja "Panel" (Paneles) y tiene sus botones dentro del formulario principal y en un panel tengo un formulario hijo, quisiera saber como ejecutar una funcion del formulario hijo dentro del panel

```
    private void AbrirFormInPanel(object FormHijo)
    {
        if (this.PanelCentral.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.PanelCentral.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        fh = FormHijo as Form;
        fh.TopLevel = false;
        fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.PanelCentral.Controls.Add(fh);
        this.PanelCentral.Tag = fh;
        fh.Show();
    }

    private void btnUsuarios_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormInPanel(new Panel_Usuarios());
    }

    private void btnES_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormInPanel(new Panel_Registros());
    }

    private void Principal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AbrirFormInPanel(new Panel_Registros());
    }
```

Por ejemplo quisiera que al oprimir el boton "btnES" tambien se ejecute una funcion que esta en el formulario "Panel_Usuarios", en el caso que el panel que este abierto sea "Panel_Usuarios"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not written in English

Comment: Lo siento pero tienes que preguntar en inglés en este sito. I‘m sorry but you have to ask in english on this page.

Comment: There appears to have been no effort to formulate the question properly. Not only is this not in English, two of your three tags have nothing to do with your question.